# pass value as year,quarter,month in oracle

Tags: oracle, birt

am having query with date column now i have to pass parameter to this single query 
like year,quarter,month.by cascading listbox.so how to vary this query according to parameter..

```
my query:

select distinct 
OUTLET_NAME,
ROUND (nvl(sum(WALKIN_WITHOUT_CGROUP),0)/ COUNT(*),2)APC,
ROUND((nvl(SUM(SALES_VALUE),0)+nvl(sum(total_sales),0)-nvl(sum(net_sales),0)+nvl(sum(discount),0))/nvl(sum(BILLS_WITHOUT_CGROUP),0))ASPB,
ROUND((nvl(SUM(SALES_VALUE),0)+nvl(sum(total_sales),0)-nvl(sum(net_sales),0)+nvl(sum(discount),0))/COUNT(*),2) ASPD,
nvl(sum(BILLS_WITHOUT_CGROUP),0) Bill,
trunc(nvl(SUM(SALES_VALUE),0)+nvl(sum(total_sales),0)-nvl(sum(net_sales),0)+nvl(sum(discount),0)) Sale,
nvl(sum(WALKIN_WITHOUT_CGROUP),0) WALKINS
from OUTLET_PAYMODE_REPORT_FACT A,OUTLET_DETAILS B
WHERE  A.OUTLET_ID=B.OUTLET_ID and SALES_VALUE>0
and tran_date  between '01-Apr-2012' and '31-Mar-2013'
group by OUTLET_NAME
```

Comment: Please be more specific as what exactly are you looking for.

Comment: from this query am looking to calculate year,quarter,month...

Comment: Write a stored procedure taking the "resultsBy" value and generate the query dynamically. "resultsBy" will be either year, quarter or month

Comment: am beginner  of oracle is there possible to produce example for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have two parameters: `parameter1` which contains the starting date of the period, and `parameter2` containing the end date. The parameters could be cascading or not.

You can make two variables which hold the values of the parameters:

```
var startDate = params["parameter1"]
```

and the same for the enddate. Alternatively, if you specify only a start date (eg, january 1 2012) and a period (month, quarter, or year) you can calculate the end date and use that as the value for your second variable.

When you've done that you can open your data set in the GUI and copy your query as JavaScript into the property binding. This re-writing the entire query into a string:

```
query line 1
query line 2
query line 3
```

becomes

```
"query line 1 "+
"query line 2 "+
"query line 3 "
```

You can then use the variables you specified:

```
"and tran_date  between '" +vars["startDate"] +"' and '" +vars["endDate"] +"'"
```

Be careful that you fill your variables with the proper date format, and make sure to include the right amount of quotes and whitespace - a `'` is easily overlooked!